# ¿Cómo puedo repetir una misma fila cierta cantidad de veces en una nueva tabla?

Tags: r

Tengo como consigna crear una tabla que sea la primera fila de la base de datos iris repetida 100 veces.
Se me ocurre la opcion "rep" pero ésta creo que es solo con numeros enteros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `rep()` ciertamente puedes resolverlo:

```
iris[rep(1, 100),]
```

Conceptuamente, estamos seleccionando 100 veces la fila 1.